# async/await not returning resolved promise

Tags: node.js, async-await

From what I understand of `async/await`, `await` causes JavaScript to pause until the `Promise` is either resolved or rejected, before it continues forward. Given the following code

```
function foo(uri) {

    … do a bunch of other stuff …

    const result = bar(uri);
    console.log('step 2 done');
    return {"uri": uri, "result": result};
}

function async bar(uri) {
    const response =  await fetch(uri);
    const result = await JSON.parse(response);
    console.log('step 1 done');
    return result;
}

const result = foo('my/server/resource');
console.log(result);
```

I expect

```
step 1 done
step 2 done
{"uri": 'my/server/resource', "result": { … bunch of data … }}
```

but I get

```
step 2 done
{"uri": 'my/server/resource', "result": {}}
step 1 done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: const result = bar(uri); you are missing await here. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for JavaScript to *know* that `bar()` returns a resolution and not a Promise object (to be maybe used later), you'd need to let it be aware of that via `await` in your `foo()` method:

```
const result = await bar(uri);
console.log('step 2 done');
return {"uri": uri, "result": result};
```

Also note that since we are now using the preserved `await` keyword, your `foo()` method must also have the `async` prefix before the method name

```
async function foo(uri) {
```

Comment: whoa! that is a very clear explanation, but it is also really screwy in terms of understanding what is going on. So, lets say I have `fn1()` calls `fn2()` calls `fn3()` calls `async fn4( return await result-from-long-running-process; )` then I would have to put `async/await` in all of the preceding functions in order for them to wait for the result from the subsequent function, right?

Comment: That's correct. The reason being that sometimes you might not want to await (meaning simply execute an async process in the background and let it do its thing) on a method's return value or sometimes you'd want to run the method and use the promise that was returned. For those (and maybe other) reasons JS runtime requires you to specify some situations with `async/await`. There's some edge cases as well, like you don't need to await a method when you're already returning its value (`return fn4()` is fine), etc. A lot of good articles on these topics : )

Comment: Another approach is to [.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) a chain of promises.  No async or await needed.  Similarly, you can also use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to await each of an array of promises, regardless of the order they complete in.

Comment: Yes, since the async/await is syntactic sugar for the Promise API, then you can always swap it out for the (debatably less readable) chained .then() syntax.